# Structures created from cell complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I've recently started stydying algebraic topology and am now learning about cell complexes.  I understand the iterative construction of such spaces, but I lack any intuition concerning the limitations on the possible resulting structures.

I thus have two questions for which I am seeking, preferably, non-highly technical answers:

1) What types of structures can, and cannot, be created iteratively from cells?

2) What types of spaces are, and are not, homotopic to the spaces created from cells?

Comment: Regarding your second question, it can be said that every cell complex is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. (I don't know whether there is a space that has the homotopy type of a CW complex but is not a cell complex.)

Comment: I can give you a non-example : [Hawaiian earrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) is not of homotopy type of a CW complex. The reason is that every CW-complex is necessarily locally contractible, which fails for the earring.

Comment: @ChesterX Indeed, the Hawaiian earring is not of the homotopy type of a CW complex, but not because it is not locally contractible! The property of being locally contractible is not homotopy invariant, as explained by studiosus [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523416/is-there-any-example-of-space-not-having-the-homotopy-type-of-a-cw-complex/523525#523525).

Comment: @DanielGerigk, thanks for pointing this out!